# Robot Framework Ride is not working on mac

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to run command on terminal on Mac `ride.py` and getting an

> error as segmentation fault 11

The Logs of the error are as mentioned below

```
Process:               Python [2126]
Path :/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Timestamp:

```
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               2.7.9 (2.7.9)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [2121]
Responsible:           Terminal [2103]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-13 10:20:19.195 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        BB484FE8-9B7B-6FB8-4160-F47065883AE5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run RIDE on mac if you change your python version from 64 bit to 32 bit according to their github: https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE. From my experience, it has been running pretty slow on MAC, but a lot faster on Windows.

You can use another IDE and there are plugins for Robot Framework for it. Just look under 'Editors'. Good luck. http://robotframework.org/#tools. From my experience, it made my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Robot framework ride work  on the mac machine  but you need  to have a 32 bit version to be installed

Also its better to use Pycharm editor on mac , it is better the the Ride Editor and also have good support for python  libraries

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked like a charm for me:

I went to this directory: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotframework_ride-2.0a1-py2.7.egg/robotide`

and then ran `arch -i386 python __init__.py`,

It launched RIDE editor and attaching the screenshot.
[image]